# How to Reorder Columns with Bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have used the following tags in bootstrap 4 .

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="right-user-account" >
                    <a href="#">User Account</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="images/logo.png">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="left-login" >
                    <a href="#">Login</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

I want to be in full-width with the logo

[image]

How do I work with the reorder command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 uses flex/flexbox. So yes you have the option of ordering elements/columns.

I think what you want is using just the Bootstrap-4 classes of `order-{number}` with your `col` classes.

**Below is the solution:**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
  
    <div class="col-md-3 col order-2 order-sm-1">
      <div class="right-user-account">
        <a class="fd-head-login" href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>User Account</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-6 text-center col-md-6 order-1 order-sm-2">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/logo.png">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 order-3">
      <div class="left-login">
        <a class="fd-head-login" href="#">Login<i class="fa fa-user"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

You can find more **[here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering)**.

[Codepen link to playaround screen widths](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YYvLxw)

Hope this answer helps you!

Comment: Thanks.It does not work . I have used ' Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6 ' . Is this the problem?

Comment: Yes bootstrap 4 alpha does not have flex box and isn't stable.

Comment: You can check here http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2017/08/10/bootstrap-4-beta/ Bootstrap 4 Beta has flexbox and not any prior versions.

Comment: Thanks . I downloaded bootstrap 4 beta and moved it with  v4.0.0-alpha.6 . But the code above is not executed correctly

Answer (score 2):

You can use reordering option of bootstrap
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering